# Multiple level grouping in a SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset returned as below:

```
Province    City    ItemID  Sales
BC  Vancouver   1111    100
BC  Victoria    1111    100
BC  Vancouver   2222    100
ON  Toronto 1111    200
ON  Ottawa  1111    100
ON  Toronto 2222    200
ON  Ottawa  2222    300
```

Bunisee requires the report to show sales for each item grouping by province and then drill down to city level of each itme. So the defalut page should like this:

```
Province        ItemID  Sales
BC      1111    200
        2222    100
ON      1111    300
        2222    500
```

When clicking the province + sign, report drills down to city level like this:

```
Province    City    ItemID  Sales
BC          
    Vancouver   1111    100
        2222    100
    Victoria    1111    100
ON          
    Toronto 1111    200
        2222    200
    Ottawa  1111    100
        2222    300
```

Answer (score -1):

Basiclly the problem is solved by the feature of Adjacent groups in SSRS 2008.

Cheers!